# How to get the last index of a substring in SQLite?

Tags: sqlite

I have a string in the table: `http://www.foo.com/hello/bar/baz` and I want to get everything that comes after the last '/' (in this case the string 'baz').

I can do substr(str, lastIndexOf(str, '/')), but I dont know how to get the lastIndexOf in SQLite.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

```
select replace(str, rtrim(str, replace(str, '/', '')), '') from table;
```

Step-by-step explanation. For example, we have the string:

`/storage/udisk/1200 Mics/[2002] 1200 Micrograms/1200 Mics - 03 - Mescaline.mp3`

The `replace(str, '/', '')` removes `/` chars from str so we will have:

`storageudisk1200 Mics[2002] 1200 Micrograms1200 Mics - 06 - Ecstasy.mp3`

Let's call this `noslashes`. Next we use [`rtrim`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#rtrim)`(str, noslashes)`, which will remove all chars that appear in `noslashes`, starting from the right. Because `noslashes` contains everything in the string except `/`, this will trim from the right until it finds the `/` char. This way we found our parent dir:

`/storage/udisk/1200 Mics/[2002] 1200 Micrograms/`

Now we remove the parent path name from the file path using `replace` and we have just the filename

`1200 Mics - 03 - Mescaline.mp3`

Comment: @ungalcrys Great! If you change your `'/'` to `'\'` you can split a Windows FullFileName to the FileName only. If cut away the first `replace(str,` and the ending `, '')` you get the Path without FileName.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to replace all occurances of `FilePath` and `TableName` in the code with the names as they appear in your table.

You will need to create a `REVERSE` function e.g. in PHP you would run the following command:

```
conn.create_function("REVERSE", 1, lambda s: s[::-1])
```

Note: Each language has its own way of creating custom SQLite commands.

`REVERSE` the `VARCHAR`, and then once the processing has finished `REVERSE` it back again.

```
SELECT 
    FilePath, 
    REVERSE(SUBSTR(REVERSE(FilePath), INSTR(REVERSE(FilePath), '\'), LENGTH(FilePath))) AS [DirectoryPath], 
    REVERSE(SUBSTR(REVERSE(FilePath), 0, INSTR(REVERSE(FilePath), '\'))) AS [Filename] 
FROM 
    TableName
```

Comment: Did you notice the sqlite tag?

Comment: Yes. That's why this is valid and tested SQLite SQL

Comment: @Knickerless-Noggins Except SQLite doesn't have CHARINDEX nor REVERSE functions.

Answer (score 0):

There are limits to sqlite core functions' expressive power. For a known maximum number of `/` characters, this can be accomplished by a series of nested `substr()` and `instr()` calls, removing parts of the string to the next `/` at a time, but that's not too elegant.

You should really do it in your programming language instead.

Answer (score 0):

The answer given by ungalcrys works great;

```
select replace(str, rtrim(str, replace(str, '/', '')), '') from table;
```

but I have 399 records that I want to replace with the value returned.

Not sure how I would do this.

I tried;

```
update Part set Filename = (select replace(Part.Filename, rtrim(Part.Filename, replace(Part.Filename, '\', '')), '') from Part)
```

but it replaced all records with a single value.