# SQLite Select Last Occurance of Character

Tags: sqlite

I'm using SQLite, and I'm unable to find a way to locate the index of the last occurrence of a character. For example, the records that I need to parse are:

```
test123.contoso.txt
testABC.contoso.atlanta.docx
another.test.vb
```

I would appreciate if anybody can point me in the direction how I can parse the file extensions (txt, docx, vb) from these records through a SQLite query. I've tried using the REVERSE function, but unfortunately SQLite doesn't include this in it's toolbox.

Comment: Are you trying to SELECT out the file extension or do a WHERE condition using the file extension or something entirely different? If the latter, try `REGEXP`

Comment: I'm trying to do a SELECT based on the file extension, for example I would like to to a SELECT DISTINCT and be able to determine all of the file extensions among the files in all of the records.

Comment: Yeah - there doesnt seem to be a remotely clean way to do this with SQLite. I would suggest doing it in your app code or starting to store the file extension separately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to check whether a file name has a *specific* extension, you can use LIKE:

```
... WHERE FileName LIKE '%.txt'
```

However, it is not possible with the [built-in functions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html) to extract the file extension.

If you need to handle the file extension separately, you should store it separately in the database, too.

Answer (score 1):

You can adapt the solution in [How to get the last index of a substring in SQLite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21388820/how-to-get-the-last-index-of-a-substring-in-sqlite) to extract the extension.

`select distinct replace(file, rtrim(file, replace(file, '.', '')), '') from files;`