# How to get the position of a character in SQLite from the right (or the last searched character from the left) with the function instr()?

Tags: ios, sql, xcode, sqlite

I try to get the last position of a character with a query with instr, but impossible to do it as the reverse() function doesn't exist in SQLite. Do you have an idea ?

```
SELECT substr(ZSTREETNAME, instr(ZSTREETNAME,',')+1) FROM ZTAB_PARTICULIER WHERE ZSTREETNAME like '%,%'
```

In the string : "Rue, test, exemple, à l'Eau, 46"
What I search : The position of the last character "," of the string
What I want : 28

Comment: Perhaps show a sample value and desired output.

Comment: I just put what I would like in the end of the message right now. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Presumably the number of `,` is variable?

Comment: Yep exactly. I have a database with 2 000 000 lines, and I need to know for each lines the position of the last ","

Comment: The replace/trim answer [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21388820/how-to-get-the-last-index-of-a-substring-in-sqlite) will allow you to pull off the last token (46)

Comment: Perfect, it works! Thank you very much.